# How to replace hello in below linux file to hello1 and next occurence of hello to hello2 and so on till the end of file

Tags: linux, shell, perl, awk, sed

```
This is a test script hello.
This is hello a test script.
This hello is a test script hello.
This is a test script hello.
hello This is a test script hello.
```

Searched but couldn't find proper explanation for above using awk or sed command.
Any guidance will be highly appreciated.

I tried below command need some modification to below to print hello string before each number

`awk '{for(x=1;x<=NF;x++)if($x~/hello/){sub(/hello/,++i)}}1' file.txt > new.txt`

Output:

```
This is a test script 1. 
This is 2 a test script. 
This 3 is a test script 4. 
This is a test script 5. 
6 This is a test script 7.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -pe's/hello\K/++$x/ge'  input.txt
```

This increments the count on each `hello`, starting with `1`.  The `\K` is a [positive lookbehind](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Lookaround-Assertions).

Answer (score 1):

`awk` still can work for your request, modify your command to,

```
awk '{for(x=1;x<=NF;x++)if($x~/hello/){sub(/hello/,"&"++i,$x)}}1' file.txt > new.txt
```

Brief explanation,

- The `&` in the `sub` is replaced with the text that was actually matched, which would be `"hello"`
- You may add the third parameter for `sub` to process `$x` only

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for word boundaries:

```
$ awk '{while(sub(/\<hello\>/,"&"c+1))c++;}1' file
This is a test script hello1.
This is hello2 a test script.
This hello3 is a test script hello4.
This is a test script hello5.
hello6 This is a test script hello7.
```